# keyup keydown jquery handling

Tags: jquery, listener, keydown

Im struggeling with the event listener for keys is jquery.

My problem is that it only fires when i let go of each key i pressed before.

As example:
Im often working with cmd+left to select my text and i still hold down cmd to copy it.
But the text only gets selected,
when i let go of command (all keys).

```
$('.komand-line').focus(function(){
    var caret='<div class="komand-caret-wrapper"><div class="komand-caret"></div></div>';
    $('.komand-fake').html(caret+$(this).val());
    $(this).on('keydown keyup mousedown mouseup mousemove',function(){
        $('.komand-fake').html($(this).val());
        startpos = $(this)[0].selectionStart;
        endpos = $(this)[0].selectionEnd;
        $('#komand .komand-caret').remove();
        if(endpos > startpos){
                var output = [$('.komand-fake').html().slice(0, startpos),'<div class="komand-selected">',$('.komand-fake').html().slice(startpos,endpos),'</div>',$('.komand-fake').html().slice(endpos)].join('');
        }else{
            var output = [$('.komand-fake').html().slice(0, startpos), caret, $('.komand-fake').html().slice(startpos)].join('');
        }
        $('.komand-fake').html(output);
    });
});
```

This is the code i use for calling the listener at the moment.
I would like to have everything done "while" the key/s is pressed.
you can test the current behaviour on http://server.hvlmnns.de/

any ideas how to prevent this?
I think i would need something like while key is pressed, but the keypress method doesen't 
work properly either.

Comment: you haven't explained what behavior you expect or what your code is supposed to do. WHat is `this` ? Show more code and a demo in jsfiddle.net might also help

Answer (score 0):

wrapping a timeout aorund the functions in the handler works just perfect.

```
function komandCaret(el,caret){
    var komandCaretInterval = setInterval(function () {
         $('.komand-fake').html(el.val());
        startpos = el[0].selectionStart;
        endpos = el[0].selectionEnd;
        $('#komand .komand-caret').remove();
        if(endpos > startpos){
                var output = [$('.komand-fake').html().slice(0, startpos),'<div class="komand-selected">',$('.komand-fake').html().slice(startpos,endpos),'</div>',$('.komand-fake').html().slice(endpos)].join('');
        }else{
            var output = [$('.komand-fake').html().slice(0, startpos), caret, $('.komand-fake').html().slice(startpos)].join('');
        }
        $('.komand-fake').html(output);
    },10);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.komand-fake').html($('.komand-line').val());
    $('.komand-fake').on('keydown mousedown keyup mouseup',function(e){
        $('.komand-line').focus();    
    });
    $('.komand-line').focus(function(){
        var caret='<div class="komand-caret-wrapper"><div class="komand-caret"></div></div>';
        $('.komand-fake').html(caret+$(this).val());
        $(this).on('keydown mousedown ',function(e){
            komandCaret($(this),caret);
        });
    });
    $('.komand-line').focus();
    $(document).on('blur','.komand-line',function(){
        $('#komand .komand-caret').remove();
    });
});
```